# Setting up a Git server

Tags: git

My team is working with several RedHat Linux servers and we'd like to synchronize our sources from one server to another (for several distinct projects).

I'd like to set-up a git-server as a version control; however I'm new to git and I'm confused by the terms ('server', "daemon', 'repository', etc...). Moreover we're working behind a firewall.

Can anyone point me to a link about how to setup a git server?

Thanks,
Pierre

**Update:** best resource I found was http://blog.commonthread.com/2008/4/14/setting-up-a-git-server but , for example how can I "use ssh keys to login so that you can have multiple developers connect securely and easily"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=README.rst;hb=master)

> gitosis aims to make hosting `git`
>   repos easier and safer. It   manages
>   multiple repositories under one user
>   account, using SSH keys   to identify
>   users. End users do not need shell
>   accounts on the server,   they will
>   talk to one shared account that will
>   not let them run   arbitrary commands.

Comment: I discovered an interesting link threw your answer: http://progit.org/book/ch4-4.html thanks

Answer (score 2):

The book [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) has a whole chapter on providing Git services: [Git on the Server](http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html). It also covers gitosis and gitolite.

Answer (score 1):

Gitosis is pretty much unmaintained; the last significant commit made was more than 2 years ago.

Gitolite is an order of magnitude more powerful and has lots of users now.

Disclaimer: I'm the author so I'm clearly biased :-)

Answer (score -1):

SSH is a fundamental tool for network security and communication and very useful for any number of tasks.  I recommend you get the basics of this down before continuing with Git.  You won't find any shortage of tutorials to help you.  I'm guessing the client computers are running Windows - Putty is the usual SSH client program for that o/s.